# Reset "style" attribute on jquery.resizable element without breaking resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, resize

[Full jsbin here](http://jsbin.com/roqeve/2/edit?js,output)

Basically, I have a "panel" that is anchored on the right side of the viewport.  I want it to be resizable horizontally.  The catch is, I want the negative space to be limited between 200px and 400px.  If that doesn't make sense, please [see the JSBin](http://jsbin.com/roqeve/2/edit?js,output) and it should be easier to understand.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var maxContentWidth;
    var minContentWidth;

    $(window).resize(function() {
      var ww = $(window).width();
      maxContentWidth = ww - 200;
      minContentWidth = ww - 400;
      $('#content').resizable("option","maxWidth",maxContentWidth);
      $('#content').resizable("option","minWidth",minContentWidth);
      //if I could even "reinitialize" the pane upon resize, but this doesn't work:
      /*$('#content')
          .css('right','10px')
          .css('top','10px')
          .css('left','200px')
          .css('bottom','10px');
          */
      //I discovered that doesn't work because jquery resizable applies a local "style" attribute, so then I tried this:
      //$('#content').attr('style','');  //this makes it completely not resizable at all

    });

    $('#content').resizable({
      handles: "w",
      maxWidth: maxContentWidth,
      minWidth: minContentWidth
    });
});
```

**update**: As you can see in the jsbin comments, I decided just reinitializing the panel on window resize was fine and should be simple to do, right?  Well, jquery resizable uses a local "style" attribute instead of modifying css.  So, I tried just clearing out the style attribute on window.resize, but if I do that I can't resize the panel at all, which doesn't make sense to me.

So.  Any ideas how I can "clear" all the styling and reset the CSS without breaking the resizable functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if i understand, but let's give a try!

http://jsfiddle.net/2eor05dt/

```
$( document ).ready(function() {

    // First Value
    var maxContentWidth;
    var minContentWidth;
    maxContentWidth = $(window).width() - 200;
    minContentWidth = $(window).width() - 400;

    $(window).resize(function() {
      var ww = $(window).width();
      maxContentWidth = ww - 200;
      minContentWidth = ww - 400;
      $('#content').resizable("option","maxWidth",maxContentWidth);
      $('#content').resizable("option","minWidth",minContentWidth);
      var gap = ww - $('#content').width() - parseInt($('#content').css('left')) - 10;
      $('#content').width($('#content').width() + gap);
    });

    $('#content').resizable({
      handles: "w",
      maxWidth: maxContentWidth,
      minWidth: minContentWidth
    });
});
```

Comment: Seems to be a small glitch after maximizing the window and restoring it, the right border doubles until you resize the panel or window again.  Definitely not a showstopper though, works 99% better than what I had.  Thanks!!!